# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "faiezahmed844@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators

Tags: laravel

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "faiezahmed844@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message - `535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u6sm1627561pfm.10 - gsmtp`.

Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message - `535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u6sm1627561pfm.10 - gsmtp`.

Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message - `535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u6sm1627561pfm.10 - gsmtp` .

Answer (score 2):

Check your email config and generate the Gmail app password.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_USERNAME // Gmail mail iD
MAIL_PASSWORD=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD // Gmail App generated password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Follow below link for generating an app password.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en